# How to customize ember-cli build to exclude source code concat

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs, ember-cli-pods

I have rather a large application, right now about 5mb for app.js and 1mb+ in vendor js. I assume it will cross 10mb, our target users are on slow internet and each user have different rights so most of the components are not available to a user.

I was thinking to exclude some big components from build process and load them on demand. So far I liked this idea https://github.com/Cryrivers/ember-remote-component/blob/master/app/components/remote-component.js where it checks if a component is loaded, if not then load them using AJAX

something like

```
if(!container.hasRegistration(`component:${ componentName }`)){
    $.when(
        $.getScript(`/remote-components/${ componentName }/component.js`),
        $.getScript(`/remote-components/${ componentName }/template.js`)
    ).done(()=> {
        let container = getOwner(this);
        container.register(`component:${ componentName }`, require(`${ ENV.modulePrefix }/components/${ componentName }`).default, {singleton: false});
        this.set('isLoaded', true);
    })
}
```

I think this can work. But here are two questions

**A:** How to exclude a component from build process, and stop it from concatenating but also keep them in */dist/components/abc/* folder

**B:** Separate compile template.hbs to template.js for that component as compiling the template after loading via AJAX will cause huge performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is not the exact solution the OP is looking for, but i think it is a better long-term solution** :

I think lazy-loaded engines might be a better way to approach this problem.
https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines

You can prevent the majority of your app from loading for most users.

Experimental support for lazy-loading is available in the master branch as per the project's README.

Comment: Yes, thanks it has landed in 2.10 and hopefully in 2.12 LTS version. I will update to Engine that time ... Thanks